# Is it possible to create a custom footer widget like chat widget?

Tags: visualforce, chatter

hey i want to show a  custom footer widget like chat  widget.Is it possible to  create a custom footer widget like chat widget?

Comment: Do you have Chatter enabled? That has a chat client - http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/messenger/faq/

Comment: @MikeChale I guess the  question is more about form-factor, not abiut the functionality that chatter provides.

Answer (score 1):

This is always possible by "rolling your own" widget via (an extensive undertaking of) Javascript in any VF page you create, but this *might* be possible to implement a custom Javascript widget for the **entire** UI by inserting the Javascript into a `Home Page Component` (<kbd>Customize</kbd> ➨ <kbd>Home</kbd> ➨ <kbd>Home Page Components</kbd>).